# Android ICS calendar issue

Tags: android, calendar, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-calendar

I am working around with the ICS calendar. The problem am facing is while insertion, updation with events in the calendar it works perfectly fine except when i delete the event from the calendar manually and query within my app for that event. The URI and the calendar_id for that particular calendar still persists in the db of the android calendar app. I want my app and the calendar to sync.
Can anyone please suggest any work around or solution for this.

Thanks in advance

dominic

Comment: you are add new calendar or event into calendar database.

Comment: i got that it was the problem with the default calendar with my galaxy s2 named "My Calendar" this calendar persist the data within the device while the other installed calendars do not.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the value of CalendarContract.Events.DELETED is not 1.

In devices with registered SyncAdapter, deletion will only update that column value to 1. This let the respective SyncAdapter to handle the deletion and do whatever it needs to do with the deleted item. Only after the SyncAdapter finished its task does the row actually deleted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11824222/android-calendar-ics-4-0-uri-after-a-reminder