# Android Calendar ICS 4.0 URI after a reminder

Tags: android, android-calendar, android-event

The problem i am facing is very unique in its own kind. Whenever i add a event to the calendar from my application and setup a reminder for "On time" its shows as a proper value in the Android calendar application. After the time has passed for eg: "set on time" for 12:15pm and as 12:15 pm is passed the android calendar application changes the "On time" to "10 mins before" automatically.

One more : Also after i set a reminder for 5 mins before and i delete the event from the android calendar application, before the time arrives for the reminder or before the alert pops up the URI is deleted and it reflects in my app. After the alert pops up and i delete it the URI still persist into the android calendar application.

Thanks,
Help Appreciated.